While Deplyoing the solana scaffold and running validators I'm not able to see it in the explorer solana custom rpc url
The whole thing started when I wanted to look at the numbers in the explorer.solana.com




I am not able to find the solution for this problem , I would highly appreciate it if you can give some directions so that I am able to get that figure locally, even check the Solana Status but it was operational but i don't know what is wrong ;)
